# Problems with target disk mode, HD does not show in Finder/Desktop (only in Disk Utility)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, target-disk-mode

I have a MacBook Pro which goes straight to Disk Utility when I try to start it (it totally froze and I forced it off and on). And no luck in repairing the hard disk (Disk Utility can't repair…)

I am trying to copy from my HD to a borrowed MacBook putting my MacBook Pro in target disk mode using a Thunderbolt cable, but the icon for my HD doesn't show in Finder/desktop. I do find it in Disk Utility and tried to repair it here as well but it failed. Is there anything I can do? Will DiskWarrior help me?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the Disk Utility window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let it sit - I have the same EXACT situation and while I was researching online, it just "popped up" and was available. It seemed like my good computer was trying to fix the bad computer first, before it mounted as ext hd.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not only does this answer the question, it might be the correct answer. USB drives get a "stealth" fsck and can often take 10 to 40 minutes to "appear" and there's not much to tip you when this is happening. Going to brew some tea is actually a decent strategy if you have a drive that's not mounting immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :). And I am sure this could be the answer in many cases. I had my MacBook connected for hours, but still could access it only trough Disk Utility. (I sent my MacBook in for repair and they had to install a new HD... so there was something seriously wrong with it.)